# Replacing dplyr::funs() within imap that refers to the .y value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

There [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57088113/how-to-replace-the-now-deprecated-funs-within-rename-at) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58044830/unique-challenge-replacing-soft-deprecated-funs) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833694/how-to-change-the-now-deprecated-dplyrfuns-which-includes-an-ifelse-argument) asking about how to replace the soft deprecated funs(), but none of the solutions worked for me.

I have a named list of tibbles and want to use the names to rename several columns in preperation for joining all the dataframes together and tidying the data.

The following code correctly changes the (de)selected column names.

```
df <- tibble("Feature ID" = c("ABC (Homo Sapiens)", "DEF (Caenorhabditis elegans)"),
              Resource = c("Homo Sapiens", "Caenorhabditis elegans"),
              Name = c("ABC", "DEF"),
              Signal1 = c(10, 20),
              Signal2 = c(80, 90))

list("first_set" = df,
     "second_set" = df) %>%
  imap(~ rename_at(.x, 
                   .vars = vars(-"Feature ID", -Resource, -Name), 
                   .funs = funs(str_c(.y, ., sep = "_"))))
```

But replacing funs with `list(~str_c(.y, ., sep = "_"))` or simply `str_c(.y, ., sep = "_")` gives the error

`Error in stri_c(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse, ignore_null = TRUE) : the ... list contains fewer than 2 elements`

I expect the error is that either the name of the dataframe or the column names are not being correctly entered into `stri_c()`, since it says that the list is too short. But I don't understand why it works in funs() while not when I change to list or simply ~.

Comment: Could you add your expected output? Is there any reason for `imap` specifically?

Comment: @NelsonGon Wasn't sure how to add the tibble output here, but running it should work fine. The expected output is simply that the columns are renamed by adding the "df1_" as a prefix.
I used imap because I'm not sure how else to refer to the names of the list of tibbles - map2 is equivalent, no? 
I'm more than happy to discover a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it gets into using too many pronouns in the same function, R gets confused. I ran the function outside of the map and it worked as expected so there's nothing wrong with your call.

If you make the function explicit and replace .x and .y with a and b it works. R can be rather pedantic sometimes

```
    list("first_set" = df,
     "second_set" = df)%>%
       imap(.,
       function(a,b){rename_at(a, 
                      .vars = vars(c("Feature ID", "Resource", 'Name')), 
                      .funs = ~{str_c(b, ., sep = "_")})})
```